# Rails: Polymorphic has_many: through workarounds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

My app allows users to follow several different model types, including other users, organizations, products, etc. Each of these models has a has_many: :histories association. My goal is to compile all the :histories of the resources the current_user is following.

My models look like this:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end

class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :historical, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows
  has_many :followed_resources, through: :follows, source: :followable
  has_many :followed_histories, through: :followed_resources, source: :histories

  has_many :followings, class_name: "Follow", as: :followable
  has_many :histories, as: :historical
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, class_name: "Follow", as: :followable
  has_many :histories, as: :historical
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings, class_name: "Follow", as: :followable
  has_many :histories, as: :historical
end

etc
```

My goal is to get the histories from all the current_user's followed resources like so:

```
@histories = current_user.followed_histories
```

But unfortunately, Rails does not allow us to traverse polymorphic association in a has_many: through relationship. Instead, it insists that we specify only a single association using the source_type option. For instance

```
has_many :followed_products, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: :product
```

Unfortunately, this approach won't work in this case, unless there's some way to recombine all the associations afterwards. For instance, if there was some way to do this:

```
has_many :followed_histories, through: {:followed_products, :followed_organizations, :followed_users}
```

Or perhaps there's yet another approach I'm not considering. I'm open to any suggestions, so long as the end result is a single array containing the combined histories of the followed resources.

Comment: I'm looking to something similar. Did you figure a way to sidestep creating all the "source_type" associations?

Comment: Not really. The closest thing I came up with was to create a factory-like class, which would simulate much of the functionality of a normal relationship. This solution is far from satisfactory, but if you want an example, you can see one [here](https://github.com/timothycommoner/adhocracy/blob/master/lib/adhocracy/membership_association.rb).